# Как адресовать сообщение конкретному пользователю?

Tags: java, spring, jms

Делаю сайт на spring и хочу сделать сервис обмена сообщениями между пользователями (так же как и в вк и других соц. сетях) и не могу понять, как реализовать режим, чтобы сообщения приходили с реальном времени. Точнее непонятно, как отправить адресовать сообщение конкретному пользователю.

Почитал, вроде многие сайты используют xmpp, а вконтакте вообще на node.js этот сервис написан. Или можно JMS API использовать? Но тогда надо отдельный сервер ставить (по типу ActiveMQ)?

Comment: твой сервис пулит в RabbitMQ (оно лучше, чем ActiveMQ), JMS из оцереди отправляет клиенту

Comment: А разве с помощью RabbitMQ или ActiveMQ можно отправить определенному юзеру?

Comment: ты создаешь очередь, а другой сервис слушает из этой очереди и делает то, что нужно

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону WebSocket-ов. Сейчас информации на эту тему много в сети. Самое популярное решение это [socket.io](http://socket.io). Там же есть Hello world пример создания чата.

Answer (score 0):

Как написал zolt, под ваши цели нужен websocket. В spring'е есть  реализация через sockjs и stomp( + встроенная очередь rabbitmq).
Хороший пример представлен на сайте spring в разделе getting started
 https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/